# High Dpi second monitor leads to crash

Tags: multiple-monitors, 15.10, display-resolution

I have Ubuntu Wily Werewolf (GNOME 3) installed on a Dell XPS 13, connected to a (relatively cheap) 4K monitor. I had huge issues with my standard resolution monitor (conflicts between the high resolution of the XPS and relatively lower resolution monitor); the 4K monitor was supposed to alleviate these issues, which it does...

...for about 30 minutes, after which the system inexplicably crashes and shows the login screen. There doesn't seem to be any excessive strain on the system, it just gives up for no apparent reason.

Has anyone else had the same issue? Any tips on how to debug this?

Thanks